# How to do statistical analysis on continuous group? Multinomial regression?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, experiment-design, biostatistics, multinomial-logit

I am looking for suggestions on statistical methods for the following study design.

- We have one control group and four treatment groups of mice.
- Sample size is 6 mice per group. The number of variables (i.e. metabolites) is about 200.
- Each treatment aims to increase the lifespan of mice. However, we do not know how long each mouse lived. **We only know on average how much longer each treatment lives than control.** For example, for treatment group 1, we know on average the mice lived 30% longer than the control, while treatment group 2 80%, etc.

What I am puzzling is this is not a group comparison (i.e. using ANOVA) or a regression, because we do not know exactly how much longer EACH mouse lives. Instead, what we know is the average lifespan of each group. Let's say we would like to perform a univariate analysis, namely analyzing variables one by one.

Here are my thoughts so far

- Conduct simple linear regression anyway, i.e. we make the lifespan of each mouse the average lifespan of its corresponding treatment group and then perform linear regression. Or
- Use multinomial regression, e.g. proportional odds model or baseline odds model, because there is an order by lifespan for these groups.

I feel either is optimal. For the multinomial regression, we are not able to distinguish 1% vs 10% and 1% vs 99%, i.e. we are taking the continuous information inefficiently. Is there a way to accommodate the magnitude of order using multinomial regression? It seems to me that multinomial regression does not distinguish *1% vs 5% vs 10%* and *1% vs 5% vs 99%*.

Are these valid methods? Or what statistical method would you recommend to conduct this analysis Thank you!

Comment: 30 experimental units but 200 variables?!?!

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yeah, I know. It is high-dimensional. Actually, let's not even worry about it for now. What I am worried about the most is the response, which is a "continuously categorical variable". We only know the average xxx% of lifespan increase for a group but do not know the exact lifespan of the mouse in that group.

Comment: Please make a more informative title!

Comment: Do you know anything about the _variability_ of lifetimes among mice within each group? Also, it's not completely clear from the question what hypotheses you want to test with this design. Is it which metabolites are associated with longevity? When during the lifespans were metabolites measured? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.